# Python2.7 how to loop urllib to download images

Tags: python-2.7, urllib, urlretrieve

I have a list of urls of some images and I want to download them 
    import urllib

```
links =  ['http://www.takamine.com/templates/default/images/gclassical.png',
 'https://dk1xgl0d43mu1.cloudfront.net/user_files/esp/product_images/000/010/120/large.png?1389980652',
'https://dk1xgl0d43mu1.cloudfront.net/user_files/esp/product_images/000/020/676/large.png?1453396324']

#urllib.urlretrieve('http://www.takamine.com/templates/default/images/gclassical.png','image.jpg')
for i in range(0,4):
    S1 = 'image'
    S2 = '.png'
    name = list()
    x = S1 + str(i) + S2
    name.append(x)

for q in links:
    urllib.urlretrieve(q,name)
```

I understand how to retrieve one at a time....when I try this code i get this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Python27/metal
>   memes/test1.py", line 17, in 
>       urllib.urlretrieve(q,name)   File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 98, in urlretrieve
>       return opener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)   File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 249, in retrieve
>       tfp = open(filename, 'wb') TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

any answers , explanations are appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `for` loop is there to create a list of filenames image0.png to image3.png, right?! That fails and produces a list of only one element ('image3.png') because you reinitialize the list inside the loop. You have to initialize it once before the loop. You can check this easily if you put a `print name` after the loop

The second problem is, that you pass a list to `urllib.urlretrieve`
Your question is not clear in this regard, but do you want to download 4 images named image0.png...image3.png from every of the given urls? That's how your code looks like.

If yes, you need a nested loop over the names in the list of filenames. I modified the code below accordingly.
But your urls already contain a filename, so I'm not sure what's the real intension.

```
links =  ['http://www.takamine.com/templates/default/images/gclassical.png',
 'https://dk1xgl0d43mu1.cloudfront.net/user_files/esp/product_images/000/010/120/large.png?1389980652',
'https://dk1xgl0d43mu1.cloudfront.net/user_files/esp/product_images/000/020/676/large.png?1453396324']

#urllib.urlretrieve('http://www.takamine.com/templates/default/images/gclassical.png','image.jpg')

# create a list of filenames
# either this code:
names = list()
for i in range(0,4):
    S1 = 'image'
    S2 = '.png'
    x = S1 + str(i) + S2
    names.append(x)

# or, as suggested in the comments, much shorter using list comprehension:
names = ["image{}.png".format(x) for x in range(4)]

for q in links:
    for name in names:
        urllib.urlretrieve(q,name)
```

Comment: BTW, `names = ["image{}.png".format(x) for x in range(4)]`

Comment: thanks @cricket_007, list comprehension is a really nice and powerful feature of python

Comment: thanks both of you...I understood my error and found a working code too....